# How to put BSc (Hons) degree I did in just a year in my CV

Tags: education

Usually people study 3 or 4 years at university to get a bachelors degree. I started studying bachelors in computer science and passed first 3 semesters in 1.5 years at country X.

Moved to UK and then I started my HND (Higher National Diploma) which was 2 years course at a local not so known college, however awarding body is a famous organization.

To convert my HND into Bachelors (Hons) I did a TOP-UP 1 year degree course and received a degree certificate from a WELL KNOWN university with 2:1 (2nd class upper division), missed 1st class by few marks.

I am already in profession with more then 6 years of professional experience and my position is of graduate.

***Now in my CV, degree from X university with Y grade in year Z... looks like a top selling point. Is such thing acceptable ? while doing so... I won't mention my HND or institute where I studied this degree course at. At the end of the day I have a degree certificate which says studied at college X awarded by university Y....***

**Update:**

I want to keep it simple by stating that I received Bsc(Hons) degree with grade 2:1, from university X year ending XXXX.

I don't want to make it prominent that I completed the degree within 1 year or at college XXX but I am afraid of being accused of hiding details on how exactly I acquired this degree.

One of the main reason for above statement is that because we have limited space on CV, so while refreshing it, I am thinking of trimming it down on education and put more of experience as I have much more of it now then I had it some years ago as a fresh graduate.

Answer (score 9):

> How to put BSc (Hons) degree I did in just a year in my CV

Except.. *you didn't*, and attempting to make it look that way on your CV is going to come across as confusing at best and deceptive at worst.

There's nothing wrong with having gone the HND -> Degree route (it's really quite common in the UK) and it's what actually happened, trying to to make your qualification look more impressive by implying that you did the whole thing at X university, (or even implausibly that you did a 3 year course in 1 year) is foolish.

In order for you to get accepted on to and complete the top-up course at X University you would have had to meet certain acceptance criteria and keep up with the work. That is a substantial achievement and no less than you having done your degree at X in the first place so why create the potential pitfall by obfuscating the truth?

Answer (score 2):

[motosubatsu's excellent answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/113828/37140), explains why you shouldn't imply either that you did the whole degree at the awarding university, nor that you completed a BSc (Hons) in one year.

If you are worried about the space taken up by listing everything as separate items (obviously using made-up dates):

> Oct 2007 to Jan 2009: Studying for bachelors in Computer Science at XXXX in Country WWW.
>
> Oct 2009 to Jul 2010: Awarded HND at YYYY College in United Kingdom
>
> Oct 2010 to Jul 2011: Awarded 2:1 BSc.(Hons) from ZZZZ University after TOP-UP 1 program.

You could shorten it to something like:

> July 2011: Awarded 2:1 BSc.(Hons) from ZZZZZ University (1-year TOP-UP following a 2-year HND awarded in 2010 by YYYYY College).

(If the final BSc. wasn't dependent on the original study in Country YYY, you probably don't need to mention that [since you've superseded it]; if it *did* form part of the credit, you should probably add the details in short-form).

Comment: I'd just put the month/year when the certificates/diplomas/degrees were awarded and not bother with the start dates.

Comment: @HorusKol That's essentially what I've done in the final "short form" entry.

Comment: The "short form" is confusing, and I wouldn't use it. I would just list the degree and diploma with the degree first

Answer (score 1):

> I am already in profession with more then 6 years of professional experience

I would suggest just put a couple of lines explaining the whole situation and stop stressing. After 6 years working, your qualification is not what people are going to focus on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are focusing on the wrong details.  For information purposes you can include the degree and what institution conferred it.  I wouldn't worry about grades once you've had your first job.  I have seen great performers with weak grades and weak performers with great grades.  So in my view, grades have a limited predictive value regarding your future job performance.

When I review a resume with 6 years of professional experience(I'm in the US), I don't even worry if you have a degree or not.  I care much more about whether you can explain and discuss the work and skills from that experience.